# Как запустить приложение flask и одновременно asyncio aiogram?

Tags: python, flask, asyncio

Делаю petproject в котором ардуино передает показания сенсоров (записываются в БД) и хочу чтобы по запросу они отправлялись в телеграм бот.

точка входа runner.py

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode

import config

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #asyncio.run(main())
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Сейчас в разделе: `if __name__ == "__main__"`: в зависимости от того, что закомментировано работает или бот или сайт. Как их заставить работать одновременно?

Comment: Не понятно зачем. Проще запустить как два отдельных приложения.